# Django model form data not being saved

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I have a profile model for the User which has fields like "bio" and "cover" representing the General information about the profile of the user etc.. 
I want those two things to be able to be edited by the User. I did everything from urls.py to forms.py to views.py to template etc and it looks like I can submit the data and it looks like its validating but the data isnt being saved.. i dont know how..

here are my files, i've included more code than neeeded just to see if maybe the code somewhere else is in fault.

note, the code that is not working is the one with "general" somewhere included in the name

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

app_name = 'profili'

urlpatterns = [
    #profile
    url(r'^$', views.ProfilePage, name='profile'),
    url(r'^edit/$', views.EditProfile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^edit/general/$', views.EditGeneralProfile, name='edit_general_profile'),
    url(r'^edit/password$', views.EditPassword, name='edit_password'),
    url(r'^edit/delete/$', views.DeleteProfile, name='delete_profile'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def EditProfile(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/profile')


    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        formpw = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
        generalform = EditGeneralProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {
            'form': form,
            'formpw': formpw,
            'generalform': generalform,
        }
        return render(request, 'profili/editprofile.html', args)



@login_required
def EditGeneralProfile(request):
    generalform = EditGeneralProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user)
    if generalform.is_valid():
        generalform.save()
        return redirect('/profile')
    else:
        print('THIS IS NOT WOOORRKIINNGGG')
```

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    followall = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='followfriend')
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    cover = models.FileField(blank=True)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditGeneralProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('bio', 'cover')
```

**template where the form actually appears in GET request**

```
 <form class="form-self general-form" method="post" action="{% url 'profili:edit_general_profile' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

          {% csrf_token %}
          {% for item in generalform %}

          <div class="full-part">
            <div class="label-par">
              <span class="label-part">{{ item.label }}:</span>
            </div>
            <div class="original-part">{{ item }}</div>
          </div>

          {% endfor %}

          <div class="full-part-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="fpartbtn">Save</button>
          </div>

        </form>
```

Comment: `print('THIS IS NOT FUCKING WOOORRKIINNGGG')` Haha, I've been there. Is that actually printing out? I bet Daniel Roseman is right.

Comment: No "This is not fucking working" is not printing out.. which leads me to believe that the thing is validating .. im a bit mad :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a form for the Profile model, so you should pass that as the instance.

```
generalform = EditGeneralProfileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)
```