# Data not being saved to database with django forms

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I am working on a django application, which contains a form. I defined the model and made the migrations. But the data is not being saved into the database. And the URL for the application gets messed up when I use submit the form.

This is my code so far

## models.py

```
class modelPost(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=12)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## forms.py

```
from .models import modelPost

class testForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = modelPost
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'phone')
```

## views.py

```
from .forms import testForm

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        testForm = testForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()
            return redirect('home')

    else:
        testForm = testForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'testForm': testForm})
```

## index.html

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ testForm.name|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ testForm.email|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ testForm.phone|as_crispy_field }}
    <input type="submit" value="check" class="save btn submit_button">
</form>
```

when I try to submit the form, this happens to the url

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?csrfmiddlewaretoken=BG2i7fSbwG1d1cOlLWcEzy5ZQgsNYzMrhDJRarXkR3JyhetpWvqNV48ExY7xM9EW&name=randomPerson&email=test%40test.com&phone=12345678
```

These are some links that I checked, but the answers dont work

[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267864/django-model-form-data-not-being-saved)

[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780907/django-form-doesnt-work-on-click-submit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did *not* make a POST request, you should specify `method="post"` in the `<form>` tag:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ testForm.name|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ testForm.email|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ testForm.phone|as_crispy_field }}
    <input type="submit" value="check" class="save btn submit_button">
</form>
```

By default the method is GET. You can actually see this, since the data is passed in the *querystring* of the URL. This thus means that the `request.method == 'POST'` check will fail, and therefore, it will indeed *not* save the data to the database.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the method in form tag , method = "post" and you need to give the path or url in form tag where you want to go after clicking the submit or check button.

```
<form method="post" acton="Enter the path or url here">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ testForm.name|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ testForm.email|as_crispy_field }}
    {{ testForm.phone|as_crispy_field }}
    <input type="submit" value="check" class="save btn submit_button">
</form>
```

Also try to pass request in form parameters like testform(request, data=request.POST), It should work now.

Comment: If you do not pass an `action` parameter, it will use the same path as the page you are currently using, hence it is not, strictly speaking, necessary.